# Can't get XPathSelectElements to work with XElement

Tags: xpath, xelement

I am creating an in-memory Xml tree using XElement.  Here is a sample of my xml:

```
<Curve>
    <Function>createCurve</Function>
    <Parameters>
        <Input>
            <BaseCurve>
                <CurveType Type="String">16fSmoothCurve</CurveType>
                <Ccy Type="String">USD</Ccy>
                <Tenors>
                     <Item Type="String">1M</Item>
                     <Item Type="String">3M</Item>
                     <Item Type="String">1U</Item>
                     <Item Type="String">Z1</Item>
                 </Tenors>
                <Rates>
                    <Item Type="String">.02123</Item>
                    <Item Type="String">.02214</Item>
                    <Item Type="String">.021234</Item>
                    <Item Type="String">.02674</Item>
                </Rates>
            </BaseCurve>
        </Input>
    </Parameters>
</Curve>
```

I am creating the xml by chaining together XElements.  For example,

```
var root = new XElement("Curve", 
    new XElement("Function", "createCurve"), 
    new XElement("Parameters"), etc);
```

I would then like to query the XElement via XPath.  For example,

```
var tenors = root.XPathSelectElements("//Tenors/Item");
var rates = root.XPathSelectElements("//Rates/Item");
```

I can successfully select a single element, for example,

```
var firstTenor = root.XPathSelectElement("//Tenors/Item");
var firstRate = root.XPathSelectElement("//Rates/Item");
```

However, trying to select multiple elements give me 0 results.

I've tried creating an XDocument and querying off of that however I get the same results.  I've also tried adding an XDeclaration to the beginning of the tree but no luck.

Why can I not query multiple elements from my XElement tree?

Thanks!

Drew

Comment: "However, trying to select multiple elements give me 0 results." - show us this code. When I set this up, `tenors.Count()` returns `4`.

Comment: As my project has too many external dependencies to really post the code I tried to create a sample project that reproduces the issue.  I can select multiple elements in my sample project so I think that it may have something to do with how I am creating the XElement my real project.  I event took the entire xml doc that I create, save to file, call XElement.Load("c:\temp\foo.xml") and it works.  I will try to reproduce and post if I can.  Other than that, is there anything in the creation of XElement tree that would prevent me from these queries?

Comment: Okay, problem is resolved.  Embarrassingly, my conclusion that I was getting no results from my XPath query was based on execution in the Immediate Window.  When you execute the query in the Immediate Window you get: 

    {System.Xml.XPath.XPathEvaluator.EvaluateIterator<XElement>}
        result: null

I assumed there were no results because I saw result: null.  After building a sample Console application to try to reproduce the issue I could not figure out the difference between my two code bases.  Thank you @AakashM for prompting me to reproduce otherwise I'd still be banging my head

Comment: Please could you post your last comment as an answer and then mark the question as answered ?

Answer (score -3):

Use XmlNodeList:

```
XmlNodeList nodesXml = root.SelectNodes("//Tenors/Item");
foreach (XmlNode item in nodList)
        {
            var tenors = item.InnerText;
        }
```

That what I do, and it works perfect.

Comment: `XMLNodeList` is System.Xml, `XElement` is System.Xml.Linq/Linq-to-XML, so that's not really relevant, even if it works.